# Unexpected behaviour when tapping on Image in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I have a series of images in a ForEach loop. Tapping an image will select it and with draw a red overlay. However when tapping on the the second image the third image gets selected. If I replace the images with simple shapes the code behaves as expected. Please see attached screen cast.

onTapGesture is set on an individual tile.

[image]

Here is the code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    let tiles = [TileClass(counter: 1 ), TileClass(counter: 2 ), TileClass(counter: 3 )]
    var body: some View {
        TilesView(tiles: tiles )
    }
}

struct TileView: View {
    
    @StateObject var tile:TileClass
    var body: some View {
                Image( tile.imageName )
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFill()
                    .overlay( tile.isSelected ? Color.red.opacity(0.5) : .clear )
                    .frame( height: 150 )
                    .cornerRadius(10)
                    .padding( .horizontal )
                    .padding( .vertical, 5 )
                    .clipped()
        .onTapGesture {
            tile.isSelected.toggle()
        }
    }
}

struct TilesView: View {
    var tiles:[ TileClass ]
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            ForEach( tiles ){ tile in
                TileView(tile: tile )
            }
        }
    }
}

class TileClass: Identifiable, Equatable, ObservableObject, Hashable{
    static func == (lhs: TileClass, rhs: TileClass) -> Bool {
        return lhs.id == rhs.id
    }
    
    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(id)
    }
    
    var id:UUID = UUID()
    @Published var isSelected:Bool = false
    var imageName:String!
    
    init( counter:Int ) {
        imageName = "img\(counter)"
    }
}
```

Any Help will be appreciated.

Comment: Is there a reason your model is a `class`? This is SwiftUI -- your model should likely be a `struct` -- it would vastly simplify what you're trying to do here.

Comment: I was sooooo frustrated with this that I was trying anything. Coming from UIKit, I really didn’t think this should be an issue, but as I was not getting anywhere I threw everything at it.

Answer (score 3):

You are not using `ObservedObject` the way it is meant to be used.
More info on how to use them can be found here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/managing-model-data-in-your-app

Try this approach using an `ObservedObject` (TilesModel) to hold and update your `tiles` and
declaring a `struct Tile` to represent the object. Works well for me.

Note, your code does work if you use `.scaledToFit()` instead of `.scaledToFill()` in your `TileView`, or put            `.frame(height: 150 )` before `.scaledToFill()`. However just because it works does not mean it is right.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var tilesModel = TilesModel()  // <-- here
    
    var body: some View {
        TilesView(tilesModel: tilesModel)  // <-- here
    }
}

struct TilesView: View {
    @ObservedObject var tilesModel: TilesModel  // <-- here
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            ForEach($tilesModel.tiles) { $tile in
                TileView(tile: $tile )
            }
        }
    }
}

struct TileView: View {
    @Binding var tile: Tile  // <-- here
    
    var body: some View {
        Image(tile.imageName)
            .resizable()
            .frame( height: 150 )  // <-- here
            .scaledToFill()  
            .overlay( tile.isSelected ? Color.red.opacity(0.5) : .clear )
            .cornerRadius(10)
            .padding( .horizontal )
            .padding( .vertical, 5 )
            .clipped()
            .onTapGesture {
                tile.isSelected.toggle()
            }
    }
}

class TilesModel: ObservableObject{
    @Published var tiles = [Tile(counter: 1), Tile(counter: 2), Tile(counter: 3)]
}

struct Tile: Identifiable {
    var id:UUID = UUID()
    var isSelected: Bool = false
    var imageName: String = ""
    
    init(counter: Int) {
        self.imageName = "img\(counter)"
    }
}
```

Comment: I was playing with a solution for this last night and basically ended up with the exact same thing. There's a lot going on here and it's hard to communicate, I think you did well here!

Comment: Thanks for your help and suggestions for improvements to the code. Still learning SwiftUI. The change to use scaledToFit() instead of scaledToFill() did get rid of the issue but deformed the image, which was not what is wanted. However, you are correct in that the issue is with scaleToFill, and I have added a solution below to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be a system bug when using scaledToFill(). The  tap gesture seems to be picking up the full image rect, including the area not drawn. Hence in my case, using a portrait orientated image will cause unexpected behaviours.  As was suggested in the following post:

[SwiftUI tap gesture selecting wrong item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69979219/swiftui-tap-gesture-selecting-wrong-item)

...to work around this issue one needs to add a .contentShape modifier which determines the area to receive the tap gesture.
Simply adding .contentShape(Rectangle()) before .onTapGesture resolved the issue for me.(as suggested by: @workingdog support Ukraine)

```
struct TileView: View {
    
    @Binding var tile:Tile
    
    var body: some View {
        Image( tile.imageName )
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFill()
            .overlay( tile.isSelected ? Color.red.opacity(0.5) : .clear )
            .frame( height: 150 )
            .cornerRadius(10)
            .padding( .horizontal )
            .padding( .vertical, 5 )
            .contentShape( Rectangle())
            .onTapGesture {
                tile.isSelected.toggle()
            }
    }
}
```

Any other suggestions and improvements will be appreciated.

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer, adding the `.frame(height: 150)` before `.scaledToFill()` worked for me.
Using `.contentShape(Rectangle())` just before `.onTapGesture`
 without the `GeometryReader` also worked for me.

Comment: Adding .frame(height: 150) before .scaledToFill() resolved the tapping problem but it distorted the image. Here is a link to the image: https://www.sticklets.co/code/Screenshot.png. I am missing something. However adding .contentShape(Rectangle()) worked. Thanks as it simplifies the issue. I will update my answer to reflect that.